# Spring Boot application without the hibernate-validator dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

I am trying to get spring-boot (spring-boot-starter-web:1.3.5.RELEASE and  spring-boot-starter-validation:1.3.5.RELEASE) working without the hibernate-validator dependency. These are the options I have:

- Option 1: Use default OptionalValidatorFactoryBean.
- Option 2: Find some other JSR 303 implementation - org.apache.bval:bval-jsr303 or anything else.

I tried option 1, and dependency injection ignores this setup and looks for hibernate-validator and fails:

```
@Bean
public org.springframework.validation.Validator validator() {
    return new OptionalValidatorFactoryBean();
}
```

With option 2, I dropped the jar on class-path and dependency injection does not pick the implementation.

It'd be nice to have a working validator flow other than hibernate-validator or, at least provide a dummy validation like option 1.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's your issue with Hibernate Validator?

Comment: It is some legal hurdle from my employer, no other technical reason

Answer (score 3):

**If you** **choose Option1**,

> Option 1: Use default OptionalValidatorFactoryBean.

From JavaDocs of [OptionalValidatorFactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/OptionalValidatorFactoryBean.html),

> This is the actual class used by Spring's MVC configuration namespace,
> in case of the javax.validation API being present but no explicit
> Validator having been configured.

Make sure [javax.validation API](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA) is present in your classpath.

=====================================================

**If you** **choose Option2**, Using [Apache BVal](http://bval.apache.org/obtaining-a-validator.html#using-the-spring-framework) instead of Hibernate Validator

> Option 2: Find some other JSR 303 implementation -
> org.apache.bval:bval-jsr303 or anything else.

```
<!-- Validator bean -->
<bean id="validator"
    class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="providerClass"
        value="org.apache.bval.jsr303.ApacheValidationProvider" />
</bean>
```

Or Using **JavaConfig**

```
@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    
    bean.setProviderClass(org.apache.bval.jsr303.ApacheValidationProvider.class);
    // bean.setProviderClass(org.apache.bval.jsr.ApacheValidationProvider.class);
    // bean.setProviderClass(org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.class);
   
    return bean;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a bean of type LocalValidatorFactoryBean instead of OptionalValidatorFactoryBean.

You can find more about this on the [spring doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation).

```
@Bean
public javax.validation.Validator localValidatorFactoryBean() {
   return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
}
```

And finally make sure only one implementation JAR of a JSR-303/JSR-349 provider like Hibernate Validator or Apache Bval is present on the classpath, not both.

Answer (score 0):

Adding maven dependencies:

```
<!-- Bean Validation -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.bval</groupId>
    <artifactId>bval-jsr</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

In action, Spring Boot output:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Binding to target MyProperties(prop1=null, ...) failed:

    Property: prop1
    Value: null
    Reason: must not be null

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```